# Retrieve an array in viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I'm trying to create a page for editing my attachments.

The Attachment Model:

```
public class Attachment
{
    ...
    private IList<JSONI18NText> titles = new List<JSONI18NText>();
    private IList<JSONI18NText> descriptions= new List<JSONI18NText>();
    ...
    public virtual IList<JSONI18NText> Titles
    {
        get { return titles; }
        set { this.titles = value; }
    }
    public virtual IList<JSONI18NText> Descriptions
    {
        get { return descriptions; }
        set { this.descriptions= value; }
    }
```

The JSONI18NText Model:

```
public class JSONI18NText
{
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

The Attachment ViewModel:

```
public class AttachmentModel
{
    public AttachmentModel() { }

    public AttachmentModel(Attachment at) {
        ...
        this.Titles = new List<JSONI18NTextModel>();
        this.Descriptions = new List<JSONI18NTextModel>();

        foreach (JSONI18NText title in at.Titles)
        {
            this.Titles.Add(new JSONI18NTextModel(title, "Title"));
        }
        foreach (JSONI18NText description in at.Descriptions)
        {
            this.Descriptions.Add(new JSONI18NTextModel(description, "Description"));
        }
    }

    [Display(Name = "Title", Description = "Title of the file")]
    public IList<JSONI18NTextModel> Titles { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description", Description = "Description of the attachment file")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public IList<JSONI18NTextModel> Descriptions { get; set; }
```

The JSONI18NText ViewModel:

```
public class JSONI18NTextModel
{
    public JSONI18NTextModel() { }

    public JSONI18NTextModel(JSONI18NText jsonI18nText)
    {
        this.LanguageId = jsonI18nText.LanguageId;
        this.Text = jsonI18nText.Text;
    }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Now, what I'm trying to achieve is an edit form with a tabbed list for the languages: for example two tabs, one for English and one for Italian, if you click on each tab you read the input value of title and description for that particular language.

Everything works like a charm: I used a view script with two partial views, one for the lists and another for the JSONI18NTextModel:

Edit.cshtml:

```
...
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Titles, "EditLabels")
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descriptions, "EditLabels")
...
```

EditLabels.cshtml:

```
@model List<CR2.Web.Areas.Admin.Models.JSONI18NTextModel>
@using CR2.Web.Infrastructure
@using CR2.Web.Areas.Admin.Models

@if(Model.Count() == 1)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model[0], "EditLabel");
}
else
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); ++i)
    {
        <div>
            <ul>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i], "EditLabel")
            </ul>
        </div>
    }
}
```

EditLabel.cshtml:

```
@model CR2.Web.Areas.Admin.Models.JSONI18NTextModel
@using CR2.Web.Infrastructure

<li>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LanguageId)
    <div>
        @Html.LabelWithTooltip(model => model.Text)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Text)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text)
    </div>
</li>
```

When I render it, it builds fields with names like "Titles.[0].Text", which is perfect I think...

The problem comes when I submit the form: "Titles" and "Descriptions" aren't populated in the AttachmentModel...(everything else is populated)

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over the list and populating each value should be something like:

```
@foreach (JSONI18NTextModel item in model) 
{
    Html.EditorFor(i => item.Titles, "EditLabels");
    Html.EditorFor(i => item.Descriptions, "EditLabels");
}
```

Then I assume you are posting only one model to the controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(JSONI18NTextModel model)
{
    // The only Model you are posting should be accessible here.
}
```

If you have a list of models on your page, then you may want to create a `Details` view where you access only one model at a time and you post only that model to the controller.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the rendering is **ok**, I can't retrieve the model once submitted the form...

Comment: I have edited with an HttpPost controller action where the model should be accessible once the form is posted. Notice if you're using a list and have the entire list in your form, then you better create a Details view.

Comment: My Edit method receives an AttachmentModel argument...my will is to have also the JSON...Model in that AttachmentModel, such as the class has been coded...